# Tableau server making additional calls to the database for each filter is ruining performance

Tags: tableau-api

We have setup Tableau pages to load "live" (with the refresh arg in the url), so performance matters (Caching in Tableau side is not an option).

When there are say 3 filters (say City, Country, PersonType) with the main query being something like "select * from PERSON_VIEW", Tableau makes a total of 4 calls to the Oracle VIEW on load (main data + once for each filter)!

The query takes 1 second or so to execute (View is complex to compose based on the session user; fully optimized nevertheless).

So, this 4 times call (actually a lot more filters in my scenario) is making the Dashboard take 4+ seconds to load! And is obviously frustrating.

From Tableau side - I would think there should be some ways to optimize this as calling the same thing 4 times is very inefficient?

From Oracle side -

a) If these were called in the same Session we could setup a Temp Table and cache the result in the first call and serve them faster in subsequent calls, but alas it's not called from the same Session :(

b) We could setup materialized views. That amounts to caching and so is not desirable.

So, any ideas to improve performance here?